# How do I set up WordPress at the root but still use /username URLs?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm setting up a website using WordPress as the main CMS. There will be lots of static pages and a blog. URLs will be:

> http://website.com/
>
> http://website.com/about
>
> http://website.com/blog

In addition to the default blog URLs, I also want to provide username URLS such as:

> http://website.com/username

*Note: These usernames have nothing to do with the WordPress blog usernames. They will be from another database.*

I'm thinking of setting up the WordPress 404.php handler to consider `/whatever` as usernames, because WordPress will not have handled them (which means they're probably usernames). In case the query string is `/whatever/something/else`, I'll display a regular 404 message, because that probably wasn't a username request.

Is this a good, acceptable way to work this out or should I be modifying the `.htaccess` to route stuff given up by WordPress into an independent `/user.php?username=whatever`? Is there any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

What about using http://www.example.com/users/whatever as the URL for the user pages? The /users/ will give you a unique URL by which to identify the user pages.

This URL format could then be redirected to /user.php?username=whatever as per your example.